# Do I have to hold all these unusual gems in my inventory?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just found out what these gems were and that I will need to collect 20-25 of them total.  I have 7 right now and I do not like the fact that they're taking up space in my inventory.  I'd like to store them in my barrel at Riverwood.  Is it possible to ditch them until I need them all?

Comment: just so you know: despite them sayin they have weight, quest items do *not* actually contribute towards your encumbrance. So they can stay there for ever and not have any gameplay impact.

Comment: I think I've confirmed this with the briar hearts by checking my weight before and after I pick one up.  It's hard to gage that, though.  Since the hearts weight only .5 units, I'd never be able to tell if my weight was x.49 or lower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the unusual gems are quest items and therefore cannot be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of Mods available to address this, I found a few.

On Nexus for Skyrim (Oldrim), we have [*Sell Unusual Gems - Stones of Barenziah*](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23431/?) by [kryptopyr](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/users/4291352).  The description of the mod is:

> Allows the player to sell "Unusual Gems" to Ri'saad without joining the Thieves Guild.

On Bethesda Net, we have *Stones Of Barenziah DROPPABLE Plus Quest Markers* by [toaDime](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim?author_username=toaDime).

This is available on:  [PC](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3010340), [XBox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3010346), and [PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3010361) (believe it or not.)

The description for this mod states:

> In addition, the stones are no longer quest items and can be dropped.
>
> Please note:
>
> 1. As a result, the stones now have WEIGHT, so you will WANT to drop them.
> 2. You will be able to break the quest if you drop them into a respawning container for example. So please don't do that. If you DO break the quest, "setstage tgcrown 30" will fix it.
> 3. The stones still don't stack unfortunately - the not-stacking is caused by the RENAMING. In fact the quest shows signs that its creator tried to fix the not-stacking problem, but was unsuccessful. Anyway, the main concern is how they clutter up the inventory and this is fixed
> 4. The stones have no physics - if you drop them in mid-air they will float.

Comment: For completeness sake, you might look up stackable stones of barenziah mod on nexus mods.

Comment: @LoreFriendly  I don't think that would actually help the OP... (I'm sure he's long since done with this, but let's presume he was still playing).  He implied he was completely ignoring the Thieves Guild, which means they would actually still be stacking in his inventory as "Unusual Gem (7)".  It only breaks stacking when you visit Vex.

Comment: Heh my bad, did not see how old this was.

Comment: @LoreFriendly No worries at all.  I'm going through all the old posts to try to fix up bad Nexus links and I found this one that had no mod suggestions, so I thought I'd add one.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to store them it'll just say "quest item, cannot be removed"

> Later when you get one of the elder scrolls, it's huge and weighs something like 25 units and even that can never be stored same that "Quest item, cannot be removes"

Comment: Quest items weigh nothing. The elder scroll can be sold to the College librarian.

Comment: my elder scroll certainly weighed, I dont play skyrim anymore but i remember getting very annoyed sometimes that i had to carry around that heavy an object... hmm i never interacted much with the librarian :P

Comment: It certainly displayed a weight, but never actually encumbered your character.